# SQL query returning two of each record

Tags: sql, postgresql

Why is this query selecting two of each record and how can I make it only select one?

I don't believe it's related to the JSON selection, but could be.

```
SELECT 
    note.*, 
    usr.first_name AS usr_first_name, 
    usr.last_name AS usr_last_name, 
    e.data->>('f' || lname.field_id::text) AS entry_last_name, 
    e.data->>('f' || fname.field_id::text) AS entry_first_name
FROM note
LEFT JOIN usr ON note.usr_id = usr.usr_id
LEFT JOIN entry AS e ON e.entry_id = note.entry_id
LEFT JOIN field AS lname ON (lname.section_id = e.section_id AND lname.type = 'name')
LEFT JOIN field AS fname ON (fname.section_id = e.section_id AND fname.type = 'first_name' AND fname.enabled = 1)
WHERE note.grp_id = 1 AND note.deleted = 0 ORDER BY note.date DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Can you supply sample data and expected results?  Are the records returned actually duplicated or are their differences in some of the columns?  I presume adding `distinct` does not fix the issue.

Comment: It's returning two of the same exact result. Where would I add distinct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably one of your `LEFT JOIN` tables has two rows for each row on the right. If you test with `SELECT *`, you should see differences in the resulting rows (unless you have complete duplicates in that table, which would be a problem).

The best way to fix it depends on information that's not available in the question. One way would be to join to a subselect (possibly a `LATERAL` join) that folds duplicates before joining so that a single row on the left is guaranteed. That's typically much more efficient than removing dupes with `DISTINCT` later.

Comment: Fixed it - There were multiple Left Joins